# Recursive function has bad performance

Tags: clojure

I am learning clojure and I am doing some exercises to practice. Currently I am working on [the next problem](https://adventofcode.com/2016/day/19):

> The Elves contact you over a highly secure emergency channel. Back at
> the North Pole, the Elves are busy misunderstanding White Elephant
> parties. Each Elf brings a present. They all sit in a circle, numbered
> starting with position 1. Then, starting with the first Elf, they take
> turns stealing all the presents from the Elf to their left. An Elf
> with no presents is removed from the circle and does not take turns.
>
> For example, with five Elves (numbered 1 to 5):
>
> 1
>
> 5         2
>
> 4  3
>
> Elf 1 takes Elf 2's present. Elf 2 has no presents and is skipped. Elf
> 3 takes Elf 4's present. Elf 4 has no presents and is also skipped.
> Elf 5 takes Elf 1's two presents. Neither Elf 1 nor Elf 2 have any
> presents, so both are skipped. Elf 3 takes Elf 5's three presents. So,
> with five Elves, the Elf that sits starting in position 3 gets all the
> presents.
>
> With the number of Elves given in your puzzle input, which Elf gets
> all the presents?

My code:

```
(ns elfos-navidad.core (:gen-class))

(def elfs (range 8977))

(defn remove-elf [elfs] 
  (if (= (count elfs) 1) 
    elfs
    (let [[first second & rest] elfs]
      (recur (concat rest (list first))))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (time (println (+ 1 (first (remove-elf elfs))))))
```

My Snippets works correctly, but it is so slow. Same problem in nodejs is extremely faster.

PS: I know that the best way to solve this problem is with linked list, but I don't know how to do it with clojure yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that `concat` is inefficient here. There is a better way to add items to the end of collection, if you use vectors:

```
(defn remove-elf-v [elfs]
  (let [elfs (vec elfs)]
    (if (= (count elfs) 1) 
      elfs    
      (recur (conj (subvec elfs 2) (first elfs))))))

user> (time (println (+ 1 (first (remove-elf-v elfs)))))
;;=> 1571
;;=> "Elapsed time: 20.128779 msecs"
```

the old one:

```
user> (time (println (+ 1 (first (remove-elf elfs)))))
;;=> 1571
;;=> "Elapsed time: 3482.966943 msecs"
```